# Rails DateTime format can't be corrected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, datetime

I have two columns in my app that are of type DateTime.

When editing an entry in the application, I am pasting

```
12/09/16 10:39
```

But when it goes to the show page, it shows:

```
16/09/12 10:39
```

When showing a simple Time.now, it shows as

```
12/09/16 12:04
```

So that's correct.

I have entered:

```
Time::DATE_FORMATS[:default] = "%d/%m/%y %H:%M"
```

In 'application.rb', 'environment.rb', created a file 'time_format.rb' in the 'initializers' folder, 'ticket.rb' in models folder. Any other suggestions as to where I can correct this?

When going to edit the DateTime value while editing the entry, it shows as

```
0012-09-16 00:59:08.000000
```

in the text_field for some reason.

Thanks.

Comment: if its a view.why cant you use @your_model_instance.created_at.strftime("%a %d/%h/%y"),which show Sunday,02/10/16 or anything the way you want to show...

Answer (score 0):

In your controller `require 'date'` and then you can pass the formatted *DateTime* to your view:

Controller:

```
require 'date'

def index
  @user_date_time = current_user.your_date_time
  @formatted_date = @user_date_time.strftime('%d/%m/%Y %I:%M').to_s
end
```

View:

```
<%= @formatted_date %>
```

Should output: **12/09/16 12:04** *(in your case)*

Take a look at the [ruby strftime](http://apidock.com/ruby/DateTime/strftime) method for more info.